# Sync a computer as an iPod: Is a way to sinc one computer's iTunes library from another in the way of an iPod available?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, external-disk, home-sharing

My computers do not have sufficient hard drive space to store my iTunes library (movies rake up space so fast!), so I have stored my iTunes library on an external hard drive.

I would like to sync some of my music to my computer's internal hard drive (say a playlist) to have music while on the go and away from my external hard drive.

Any solution?

It would be great if we could do it in a similar way to syncing.  Copying files and creating a fresh iTunes library every "sync" seems unproductive.

Comment: Are you familiar with Unix-level symbolic links? I can elaborate this into an answer but if you are not familiar with them at all you may do more harm than good that way.

Comment: @patrix, I am only vaguely familiar with symbolic links which act as an alias.

Comment: Is your iTunes library *without movies* big enough to fit on your internal drive?

Comment: If I remove movies and podcast I have enough space, but would love to keep storage on my internal HD to a minimum (ie. a playlist) and still have some of the podcasts and movies.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend looking into iTunes Match.

It allows you to sync all your music across multiple computers, iPads, iPhones, and iPods.  Not only that, but it will let you stream music that is in the cloud that you have synced and not on your computer.  This may be a good solution for you when you want to listen to songs but don't have them on your machine.  It is 25 dollars a year and it does require a internet collection to stream.

You can also just download a playlist of songs you want to listen to if you need to have the songs with you when you don't have an internet connection.

It also syncs playlist together between all your machines.  Also, in iOS 6, it will allow you to stream the music as well.

It also works with music that you have ripped and not purchased.

You can read more here:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/

I know it isn't the most perfect solution but at least it will probably save you from a few headaches of trying to make sure things sync between the hard drive and your external.